# Failed to import outputs: Transaction extra has unsupported format at index 17

Tags: monero-wallet-cli

So today I decided to check my offline wallet and make some donations.

Fire up monero-wallet-cli on the hot machine, connect to monerod and do the usual:

`export_outputs outputs`

Then I move that outputs to the offline machine, start monero-wallet-cli and do:

`import_outputs outputs`

All I get is: "Failed to import outputs: Transaction extra has unsupported format at index 17"

So I tried to `rescan_bc` on the hot wallet and no chance, the outputs still can't be imported. Now both the hot and cold wallet are showing different balances because outputs can't be imported and I believe my wallet is unusable now that UTXO aren't properly tracked in the hot wallet. I have already tried to export key images and importing to hot wallet anw in case that error is just a warning but the balances shown still differ.

Monero version: 0.11.1.0 for Linux 64bit.

OS of monerod: ArchLinux, updated a few minutes ago.

OS of monero-wallet-cli: Fedora-25 guest inside QubesOS 3.2.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be fixed one this PR is merged: https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/3065